# Corrupted pdf after sending via Gmail API

Tags: python, email, encoding, gmail, attachment

I am currently trying to send a pdf attachment via Gmail API, but the file that I receive seems to be corrupted. Here is the code that I use to create the Email.

```
message_out = MIMEMultipart()
content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(attachment)
if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
    content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)  


with open(attachment, 'rb') as fp:
        msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
        msg.set_payload(fp.read())
filename = os.path.basename(attachment)
msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
msg.add_header('Content-Type', main_type, name=filename)
msg.add_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', '7bit')
email.encoders.encode_base64(msg)
message_out.attach(msg)

return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message_out.as_bytes()).decode()}
```

When I try to open the attachment, I then get a "failed to load PDF document". I guess it has something to do with the encoding, but I cannot figure out why, I was thinking that email.encoders was going to solve all my problems. (same problem happens with png image)

Thank you very much,
Djazouli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, this was an encoding issue, the line

```
msg.add_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', '7bit')
```

shouldn't be there